# Replace selected cells using index Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace selected cells using the index.

I found that the single cells can be changed individually using

```
df.loc
```

However, I want to change a large set of data

The data I have is

```
        Colour

0       R

1       R

2       R

3       P

4       P

5       P 

.
.
.

1000    Y

1001    Y
 
1002    Y
```

which is too large to change them individually.

I want the output to be

```
        Colour

0       Red

1       Red

2       Red

3       Pink

4       Purple

5       Purple

.
.
.

1000    Yellow

1001    Yellow
 
1002    Yellow
```

I want to use the range of index to replace the cells since the same cells (same color) are consecutive.

The index for `"Red"` is [:3], `"Pink"` is [3:4], `"Purple"` is [4:1000], `"Yellow"` is [1000:].

Comment: Unless there is a way to tell the difference between the `"P"` that is `"Pink"` and the `"P"` that is `"Purple"` then there is no way to do it.

Comment: The only things that I know are the indexes. I know the index for `"Pink"` is 3 and the index for `"Purple"` is 4 to 7.

Comment: Update your question with the list / dict of indexes.

Comment: @Lyliie - Then create list or array by index positions and assign back. Only necessary explain how is specified values with start and end index values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need set values by ranges of values, here defined in dictionary of tuples use list comprehension for repeat keys by values in `range`s and then assign to new column:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=15)})

d = {"Red": (0, 3),
     "Pink" :(3, 4),
      "Purple":(4, 10),
      "Yellow" :(10, len(df))}
 
r = [k for k, (s, e) in d.items() for x in range(s, e)]
print (r)
['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 
 'Pink', 
 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Purple',
 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']

df['new'] = r
print (df)
    A     new
0   2     Red
1   2     Red
2   6     Red
3   1    Pink
4   3  Purple
5   9  Purple
6   6  Purple
7   1  Purple
8   0  Purple
9   1  Purple
10  9  Yellow
11  0  Yellow
12  0  Yellow
13  9  Yellow
14  3  Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace` method of DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(["R", "R", "B", "B", "Y", "Y"])
>>> df.replace({"R": "Red", "B": "Blue", "Y": "Yellow"})
        0
0     Red
1     Red
2    Blue
3    Blue
4  Yellow
5  Yellow
```

Try this method first and if it's too slow, we will find another solution.

**Edit**:

```
idx = [("Red", (0, 3)),
       ("Pink", (3, 4)),
       ("Purple", (4, 1000)),
       ("Yellow", (1000, 1003)]  # or len(df)

clr = pd.Series(itertools.chain(*[[c] * (i[1] - i[0]) for c, i in idx]))

>>> clr
0          Red
1          Red
2          Red
3         Pink
4       Purple
         ...
998     Purple
999     Purple
1000    Yellow
1001    Yellow
1002    Yellow
Length: 1003, dtype: object
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same letters for different colours... In that case, how can I change it? I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

For a more numpy directed approac- since you know the indices you can calculate how many times you expect to see each value in order (see 3 reds, 1 pink, 996 purples, 3 yellows).
You can use this information to construct a categorical array very quickly.

```
codes = np.repeat([0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 996, 3])
labels = ["Red", "Pink", "Purple", "Yellow"]

out = pd.Categorical.from_codes(categories=labels, codes=codes)
print(out)

['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Pink', 'Purple', ..., 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Yellow']
Length: 1003
Categories (4, object): ['Red', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'Yellow']
```